# How do I do a switch statement using cases as strings in a combo box?

Tags: c#, combobox, switch-statement

This is what is inside my Combo Box.

```
Runescape
Maplestory
League of Legends
```

Here is the code I tried using switch statement.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case "Runescape":
            MessageBox.Show("You are playing RS");
            break;

        case "Maplestory":
            MessageBox.Show("You are playing MS");
            break;

        default:
            MessageBox.Show("You're playing League");
            break;
    }
}
```

It's giving me an error that it won't let me implicitly convert string to int.

I want to use the cases as a string instead of a number. How do I do that?

---

Also, just out of curiosity if it works where we can get part of a string as a case instead. Pretend the combobox said "Runescape 3" instead of "Runescape". I'm not sure if C# can recognize part of the string.

```
case "Runescape":
        MessageBox.Show("You are playing RS");
        break;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either `string` or `int` to compare.

**1.** if you want to `compare` with `String` use the `SelectedItem` property of `ComboBox` control.

Try This:

```
switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim())
    {
        case "Runescape":
            MessageBox.Show("You are playing RS");
            break;

        case "Maplestory":
            MessageBox.Show("You are playing MS");
            break;

        default:
            MessageBox.Show("You're playing League");
            break;
    }
```

**2.** if you want to `compare` with an `Index` use `SelectedIndex` property of an `ComboBox` Control

Try This:

```
        switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                MessageBox.Show("You are playing RS");
                break;

            case 1:
                MessageBox.Show("You are playing MS");
                break;

            default:
                MessageBox.Show("You're playing League");
                break;
        }
```

**3.**  if you want to get only first part of `SelectedItem` from `ComboBox` use `Split()` function.

Try This:

```
           switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ')[0])
            {
                case "Runescape":
                    MessageBox.Show("You are playing RS");
                    break;

                case "Maplestory":
                    MessageBox.Show("You are playing MS");
                    break;

                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("You're playing League");
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Uh what does Trim() do?

Comment: Also, just curious if my edited code will work. I've added some code below my original. If not then I'll just revert the edit.

Comment: @puretppc : so you want to add an index also to the `SelectedValue` right?

Comment: No, I still want it to keep it in string form. Guess C# doesn't recognize "Runescape" when the combo box said "Runescape 3"?

Comment: @puretppc : if you want to get only first part of SelectedItem from ComboBox use Split() function , see my edited answer with 3rd option.

Comment: @Downvoter : can you please explain where is the mistake in the code?

Comment: @puretppc : no no :) I was asking the one who Downvoted..not you , I didnt tag you there....

Comment: @puretppc : did you get what you wanted using 3rd option or not?

Comment: Yeah it's fine. Thanks. For some reason I actually got the notification of your comment even though I didn't get tagged.

Answer (score 4):

Comboboxes have three ways of getting what you want out of them:

- `SelectedItem`: The actual object that is associated to the index.
- `SelectedIndex`: The integer (zero-based) index of what was selected.
- `SelectedValue`: The value of the `SelectedItem` (using the `SelectedValuePath`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
switch (Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedItem))
{
  //...
}
```

Use `Convert.ToString()` to convert it to string in a safer way.

Comment: Could you explain how `Convert.ToString()` is "safer" than `object.ToString()`?

Comment: @Lightning_A it just involves null checking, using `Convert.ToString()` will return null if the object is null whereas `object.ToString` will throw exception. However that was the past. Now you can use the null propagation operator by `?.`. So it can be written as `object?.ToString()`, which is much more preferable now.

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion, but your current approach is not very extensible. Adding more games requires you to add on to this switch statement. Also, from the looks of things, the logic required to start playing the selected game will be very tightly coupled with your UI code. It would be better to define an interface, say ‘IGame’, which could define a Name property and a StartPlaying() function. The three games could then be defined as three separate classes that would implement this interface. Then the ComboBox could be bound to a collection of IGame objects. When the button was clicked, we would just have to call combobox1.SelectedItem.StartPlaying(), no matter which game the user had selected.

I’ve been out of the WinForms world for a while, so I’m not 100% sure if that would work without first type-checking and casting combobox1.SelectedItem to an IGame. But regardless, I think you'll find this approach to cause less frustration in the future.

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but polymorphism is awesome for stuff like this.